# LINQ: Read an Excel file and then writing to database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-excel

I am taking rows from an Excel file using LinqToExcel and then writing to SQLServer using LINQToSQL.  It DID create records in the database but with null values.  I wonder if I need to map the Mac object(linqtoexcel) to the HSD_TELE_INSTALLs object?  I don't think I am too far off since it inserted records.  Relevant code is below.  Thanks in advance.

```
        //LINQ
        var macs = from x in excel.Worksheet<Mac>(sheet)
                   select x;
        //ITERATE WITH LINQ RESULTS
        foreach (var x in macs)
        {
            HSD_TELE_INSTALL myRecord = new HSD_TELE_INSTALL();
            db.HSD_TELE_INSTALLs.InsertOnSubmit(myRecord);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }

    public class Mac
    {
        public string REGION { get; set; }
        public string MACID { get; set; }
        public string HOUSEKEY { get; set; }
        public string HOUSENUM { get; set; }
        public string STREET { get; set; }
        public string UNIT { get; set; }
        public string ADDRESS2 { get; set; }
        public string COMMUNITY { get; set; }
        public string STATE { get; set; }
        public string ZIPCODE { get; set; }
        public string TECHNICIAN { get; set; }
        public string JOBNO { get; set; }
        public string JOBTYPE { get; set; }
        public string CLOSEDATE { get; set; }
        public string CLOSETIME { get; set; }
        public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
        public string MGT { get; set; }
        public string COMPLETIONCODE { get; set; }
        public string TCRSN { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new uninitialized object of type `HSD_TELE_INSTALL` and then you're submitting it to DB.

You should initialize it somehow from `x`. Something like:

```
HSD_TELE_INSTALL myRecord = new HSD_TELE_INSTALL(){SomeField=x.SomeField /*etc...*/ };
db.HSD_TELE_INSTALLs.InsertOnSubmit(myRecord);
db.SubmitChanges();
```